# Prioritizing "$_.Name" over "$_.LastAccessTime"

Tags: powershell, operator-precedence

I created a script that allows me to search for and ignore directories from a `Remove-Item` statement, and the script *works*, but not necessarily to the extent I need it to.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path |
  Where-Object {
    ($_.LastAccessTime -lt $Limit) -and
    -not ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $True -and $_.Name -contains ("2013","2014","2015"))
  } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
```

This script is currently finding and deleting all objects that

1. Have not been accessed in the given time period

But what I need this script to do is find and delete all objects that

1. Have not been accessed in the given time period AND
2. Exclude directories that contain the name of "2013", "2014", or "2015".

I'm not arguing that the script "isn't working properly", but the thesis of my question is this:

How do I program this script to look at the directory name first, and then the last access date? I don't know *where and how* to tell this script that the `$_.Name` needs to take precedence over the `$_.LastAccessTime -lt $Limit`.

Comment: I guess one way would be to just have two different where pipes.  Something like this: `Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer -eq $True -and $_.Name -contains ("2013","2014","2015")) } | Where-Object { ($_.LastAccessTime -lt $Limit) } `

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it appeared to do the exact same thing, but that may be because of what @Ansgar mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the logic of your condition is this:

> Delete objects that were last accessed before `$Limit` and are not folders whose name contains the array ["2013","2014","2015"].

The second condition is never true, because a string can never contain an array of strings.

Also, the last modification time is stored in the `LastWriteTime` property.

What you actually want is something like this:

```
Where-Object {
  $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Limit -and
  -not ($_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match '2013|2014|2015')
}
```

If the directory names consist only of the year and nothing else you could also use this:

```
Where-Object {
  $_.LastWriteTime -lt $Limit -and
  -not ($_.PSIsContainer -and '2013','2014','2015' -contains $_.Name)
}
```

Note the reversed order of the last clause (`array -contains value`).

Comment: I tried this and it appeared to not delete anything anymore. The limit I have set is 90 days and there are files in there that are well over 180 days old. I commented out the
    **$_.LastAccessTime -lt $Limit -and**

and it still didn't seem to delete any files at all.

Here are my files for reference if it helps at all:
http://imgur.com/N6YgHWk

Comment: @AustinKargl Last access != last modification. You're looking for `LastWriteTime`.

Comment: Changing this value to `LastWriteTime` unfortunately didn't change the result. The code, although not excluding my directories, was working as intended with `LastAccessTime`

Comment: @AustinKargl Please provide evidence. Update your question with your modified code and show sample output of `Get-ChildItem | select Name, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime` for objects that should and should not be removed.

Comment: I noticed that when I was replacing my code with yours, I was also removing the `gci` cmdlet. After correcting that, your second piece of code does exactly what I need it to. Thank you very much, @Ansgar!